# How do I order Firebase data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a forum/news feed type application and currently trying to create the actual news feed/forum. So far I have a tableview which is populated by the posts consisting of the user's display name, profile picture and post text.

The issue I'm having is that it is not ordered. It displays in an unpredictable order which changes each time the application is relaunched. I have tried using ".queryOrdered(byChild: "Timestamp")" but it does not seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it ordering it or what are you getting?

Comment: It seems to be grouping them by display name but there is not set order. When I relaunch the application the list may be reversed.

Comment: I don’t believe it’s actually ordering them at all.

Comment: I see, in your database that you provided there is a space between timestamp and ", try to be sure if there is actually a space or not..

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on from the data you shared. Can you add a snippet of your actual JSON to the question (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also: does the nested observer make any difference to the result? I.e. if you log the keys of `Posts` in the outermost observes, are those keys in the order you expected them?

Comment: Ah my apologies there is no space in my actual database.

Comment: And yes I will provide a snippet of the JSON momenterally

Comment: Okay I've updated my post with my actual JSON. And yes each post has the correct corresponding display name, profile picture and text if that's what you are asking. They are just not in order.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. That is likely because I don't understand enough of what your problem is. So I wrote what I did and what output I get into an answer below. If you're getting different results, let me know. If you're getting the same results, but it's not the problem, please update your code to be similarly isolated (e.g. printing output instead of adding it to views), to get a minimal repro of your problem.

Comment: Okay I will do that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I simplify your code to:

```
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("49242360/Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "Timestamp").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in        
    for child in (snapshot.children) {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        let timestamp = dict["Timestamp"]!

        print("Key \(snap.key), Timestamp \(timestamp)")
    }
})
{(error) in
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

It prints:

```
Key -L7I6Bc5MeUgiOxkzKhF, Timestamp 1520739076.673202
Key -L7I6dBS7f43e49Xuhk1, Timestamp 1520739193.693312
Key -L7IRX8Uj89LLvymgTjA, Timestamp 1520744669.853121
Key -L7IReX4TqzXcwlbphji, Timestamp 1520744704.257354
...
```

Second run:

```
Key -L7I6Bc5MeUgiOxkzKhF, Timestamp 1520739076.673202
Key -L7I6dBS7f43e49Xuhk1, Timestamp 1520739193.693312
Key -L7IRX8Uj89LLvymgTjA, Timestamp 1520744669.853121
Key -L7IReX4TqzXcwlbphji, Timestamp 1520744704.257354
...
```

So that seems pretty reliable in ordering.

When I expand it to also log the UID and then load the user names, I get this code:

```
var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("49242360/Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "Timestamp").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for child in (snapshot.children) {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        let timestamp = dict["Timestamp"]!

        let userWhoPosted = dict["User"] as! String

        print("Key \(snap.key), Timestamp \(timestamp), User \(userWhoPosted)")

        databaseRef.child("49242360/Users").child(userWhoPosted).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            (snapshot) in
            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                print("User \(snapshot.key), Name \(userDict["Display Name"]!)")
            }
        })
    }
})
{(error) in
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

And this output:

```
Key -L7I6Bc5MeUgiOxkzKhF, Timestamp 1520739076.673202, User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1
Key -L7I6dBS7f43e49Xuhk1, Timestamp 1520739193.693312, User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1
Key -L7IRX8Uj89LLvymgTjA, Timestamp 1520744669.853121, User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1
Key -L7IReX4TqzXcwlbphji, Timestamp 1520744704.257354, User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1
Key -L7IS-vOHvHaSWp_HRiT, Timestamp 1520744795.927767, User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1
Key -L7IcTRvi0dL9HCPTiSE, Timestamp 1520747800.437907, User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1
Key -L7IdWlpJ8zLwI3YIvi7, Timestamp 1520748076.208767, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7IdboVraORS1-xTQMM, Timestamp 1520748100.956265, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7IgTX0XFbu9YC2mX6W, Timestamp 1520748849.399632, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7IvDLm1M9lmMJDmu5u, Timestamp 1520752715.24575, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7JOOepHWvxU6CbaEPO, Timestamp 1520760625.902419, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7JOS1zOsB9Tf0TCsOL, Timestamp 1520760639.73502, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7JWCQmnZhqmxC-vYqC, Timestamp 1520762672.943332, User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2
Key -L7JhX9BImuv0DAtjeBN, Timestamp 1520765903.561222, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7JhYbvMr-xvUCcZUdo, Timestamp 1520765909.560808, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7KtGXoMUEgAorrfCDm, Timestamp 1520785758.446064, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7KwK-VtU9vKtLg8F-x, Timestamp 1520786559.068727, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7KwQRUpjEa9fDTLz3g, Timestamp 1520786585.436313, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7Kwgo_XBLCjomFipQ5, Timestamp 1520786656.609396, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7L-X5vy3THn_bfq7vM, Timestamp 1520787661.309544, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7LcY7xebZPkIkmZ3dX, Timestamp 1520798151.346764, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7NOP4oE8ezfD8XyXxs, Timestamp 1520827736.498612, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7NOSlCNPTxTautJNOl, Timestamp 1520827751.563096, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7NVUR_P1yu5GFgism5, Timestamp 1520829593.437312, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7NZoYHvCeqXXUjOUZC, Timestamp 1520830728.45705, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7NZv6K8EtI97ZRHOl7, Timestamp 1520830755.339643, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7N_MvoCFV8nOszdcQn, Timestamp 1520830873.384209, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7QBKRzDxu-SvGGDs8S, Timestamp 1520874641.275255, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
Key -L7QCQueKovJpOVhxEfR, Timestamp 1520874929.892702, User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1
User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1, Name dkkdd
User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1, Name dkkdd
User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1, Name dkkdd
User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1, Name dkkdd
User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1, Name dkkdd
User HfxlCKx4uYhf09TF8fPITdNQtlo1, Name dkkdd
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User 2ul1ZpfLtxTv4KodiNBLUvKAcgo2, Name joeyhhh
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
User PQlpt0gStuNH5qICZFzTJYWrhjx1, Name dnndddmdmd
```

This again looks fine to me, although I'd definitely recommend only loading each user once (and thus keep a map of users you've already recently loaded).

Comment: Could it be a problem elsewhere in the code then? My tableview order is unpredictable and always has been. I only recently added the ".queryOrdered(byChild: "Timestamp")" to try and correct this but the tableview order was not even affected by that. The order is still incorrect.

Comment: Ok I think the problem is happening in the func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell function, I had the variables print there and it seemed to be really buggy, does this function look correct to you?

Comment: Never fixed my issue so decided to rewrite my code and go about it another way, but thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "Timestamp").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

is correct, but in the database you have many `TimeStamp` with the same value, `"Timestamp" : 1.520786656609396E9,` that is why everytime you are getting a different order.

Comment: I think you may be mistaken. I can only find one Timestamp value = 1.520786656609396E9

Comment: I also tried to order by other things to test the code, such as by Text or User but there was no difference